# Android Collapsing toolbar has too much padding

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a collapsing toolbar set like this:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:collapsedTitleGravity="right"
            app:paddingStart="5dp"
            app:titleEnabled="true"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="top|center_horizontal"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="0dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="0dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginTop="0dp">

        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>
            <com.ashojash.android.customview.VenueScoreIndicator android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                                 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                                                                 android:id="@+id/venueScoreIndicator"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- As our statusBar is transparent below and content is moved behind our toolbar has to include the padding on top so we use this area -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

[image: image showing the extra padding]
As you see there is some extra padding in top and bottom of the collapsed title, I dont see any option to set `app:collapsedTitlePaddingTop` to 0dp.
What Am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

To remove all the margins
Just use

```
app:expandedTitleMargin="@dimen/your_dimen_value"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the `RelativeLayout` with `match_parent` height. Try to remove it, if the problem has solved, write your layout somehow without `match_parent` height

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.....it will be helpful

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```